# How to parse a variable number of command line arguments with quotes into eval?

Tags: bash, shell, arguments, parameter-passing, eval

I got this simple script:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
eval "${@:2}"

while [ true ]
do
    FocusApp=`xdotool getwindowfocus getwindowname`

    if [[ "$FocusApp" == *"$1"* ]];
    then
        wmctrl -ir $(xdotool getactivewindow) -b add,maximized_vert,maximized_horz
        break
    fi
done
```

I run it like this:

```
$ ./maximize.sh "Sublime Text" /usr/bin/subl -n "./My File With Spaces in the Name"
```

But when I run it, `Sublime Text` tries to open a file named `My`, another named `File`, and etc. If I replace the `eval "${@:2}"` with:

```sh
eval "\"$2\" \"$3\" \"$4\" \"$5\" \"$6\" \"$7\" \"$8\""
```

Then, Sublime Text correctly opens the file `"./My File With Spaces in the Name"`. How to make `eval` correctly understand all argument quotes with a variable number of command line arguments, i.e., without hard coding `"\"$2\" \"$3\" \"$4\" ..."`?

Comment: Why `eval` at all? Wha't about: `"$2" "${@:3}"`?

Comment: Or even just `"${@:2}"` -- you don't have to specifically extract $2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easier to just leave `eval` out of it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
"${@:2}"
```

Example:

```
$ ./myscript "Demo" 'printf' 'This is one argument: %s\n' 'One long arg' 'Another, with * and such'
This is one argument: One long arg
This is one argument: Another, with * and such
```