# How to make runuser correctly forward all command line arguments, instead of trying to interpret them?

Tags: bash, shell, arguments, parameter-passing, eval

I got this simple script:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
SOURCE_USER=$USER
DESTINE_USER=$1

id -u $SOURCE_USER > /dev/null 2>&1

if [ "$?" == "1" ] || [ -z $SOURCE_USER ]
then
    printf "Error: Invalid source user '$SOURCE_USER'\\n"
    exit 1
fi

if [ -z $DESTINE_USER ]
then
    printf "Error: Invalid destine user '$DESTINE_USER'\\n"
    exit 1
fi

SOURCE_GROUPS=$(id -Gn ${SOURCE_USER} | sed "s/${SOURCE_USER} //g" | sed "s/ ${SOURCE_USER}//g" | sed "s/ /,/g")
SOURCE_SHELL=$(awk -F : -v name=${SOURCE_USER} '(name == $1) { print $7 }' /etc/passwd)

id -u $DESTINE_USER > /dev/null 2>&1

if [ "$?" == "1" ]
then
    printf "Creating destine user %s\\n" "$DESTINE_USER"
    useradd --groups ${SOURCE_GROUPS} --shell ${SOURCE_SHELL} --create-home ${DESTINE_USER}
    passwd ${DESTINE_USER}
    xhost '+si:localuser:$DESTINE_USER'
    sudo usermod -G "$SOURCE_USER" "$DESTINE_USER"
else
    printf "Updating destine user '%s' with groups '%s' and shell '%s'\\n" "$DESTINE_USER" "$SOURCE_GROUPS" "$SOURCE_SHELL"
    sudo usermod -a -G "$SOURCE_GROUPS" "$DESTINE_USER"
    sudo chsh -s "$SOURCE_SHELL" "$SOURCE_USER"
fi

sudo runuser sublime_vanilla -c "${@:2}"
```

I run it like this:

```
$ bash run_as_user.sh sublime_vanilla /usr/bin/subl -n "./New Empty File"
```

But when I run it, I got this error:

```sh
runuser: invalid option -- 'n'
Try 'runuser --help' for more information.
```

But if I replace `sudo runuser sublime_vanilla -c "${@:2}"` with `sudo runuser sublime_vanilla -c "\"$2\" \"$3\" \"$4\" \"$5\" \"$6\" \"$7\" \"$8\" \"${@:9}\""`

Then, Sublime Text correctly opens the file `"./New Empty File"` in a new window.

How to make `runuser` correctly understand all argument with a variable number of command line arguments, i.e., without hard coding `"\"$2\" \"$3\" \"$4\" ..."`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is slightly different from [your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55012282/7552) because you have to make the expansion of the arguments into a single string for the -c option.

The bash [printf formatter %q](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-printf) is your friend here:

```
cmd=$( printf '%q ' "${@:2}" )
sudo runuser sublime_vanilla -c "$cmd"
```

On the other hand, a quick perusal through the runuser man page suggests:

```
sudo runuser -u sublime_vanilla "${@:2}"
```

---

Another thought: `sudo runuser -u sublime_vanilla -- "${@:2}"` with the double hyphens to indicate the end of the runuser options.

Comment: I also tried your second suggestion `sudo runuser -u sublime_vanilla "${@:2}`, but it gives the same error as my original question: `runuser: invalid option -- 'n'`. Hence, using your `printf` trick worked `cmd=$( printf '%q ' "${@:2}" )`

Comment: Another thought: `sudo runuser -u sublime_vanilla -- "${@:2}"` with the double hyphens to indicate the end of the runuser options.

Comment: This last one `sudo runuser -u sublime_vanilla -- "${@:2}"` worked too!

Comment: That's good. I think that should be your preferred option as you don't have to play tricks stringifying an array.

Comment: Ah, but `stringifying an array` is much way cooler and using `--`!